# Spam filter for ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net

I'm looking for a spam filter that I can integrate into my ASP.NET application. I don't want any delegate services (e.g. Akismet) as I'm doing this for a high traffic website, any suggestions?

Edit:
I mean a post spam filter, it's a forum based website.

Edit:
Thanks for your answer but I'm not looking for a Captcha, I'm looking for a spam filter, Captcha is not a spam filter it's used for preventing automated spam but it's not a spam filter itself, a spam filter is a piece of software that scans the posts and mark them as spam or not. Actually I already have a Captcha in my application for preventing automated spam.

Comment: If your CAPTCHA isn't working, shouldn't you try a new CAPTCHA?  There are a buttload of them out there, and that's normally easier than trying to filter the spam out.

Answer (score 3):

You could check out [nBayes](http://codecube.net/2009/05/bayesian-filtering-with-c/), a C# implementation of [Paul Graham's plan for spam](http://www.paulgraham.com/spam.html)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't want to use CAPTCHA's, because they annoy people, and you already the site up and running, you could write your own parser to filter out spam.  Most spam you see is extremely blatant. Posting hundreds of links in a post.  Subject, Body, and Poster name are all exactly the same.  Other stuff along those lines.  You could write some simple filters, like I did for my blog, to basically cut out 99% of the spam, while your users don't even realize that you are even using filtering.

Comment: That's impressive -- what language did you write it in, and how well is it doing?  Are you thinking about releasing it to codeproject?

Comment: It's done with about 30 lines of REGEX statements in PHP.  Basically just checking for the number of links.  The rest of the stuff, like checking if the subject is the same as the body is pretty straightforward.  It's stopped just about all the spam from my blog, Maybe one or two a month get through

Answer (score 2):

I use [Akismet](http://akismet.com/) for spam filtering. There is a .NET interface for available [here](http://www.codeplex.com/AkismetApi) on CodePlex.

It works very well and the Api is pretty simple. Akismet is free for personal use (making less than $500/month), so I'm not sure about the pricing if you are making some serious money on the website.

Answer (score 0):

Although not widely used, since comments/forum posts are typically stored in a database, an insert trigger works remarkably well which looks for certain words in comments and auto triggers a delete. Again, this isn't an ideal solution, but it works for me. There is the possibility of deleting a legit post, but then again, its sometimes near impossible to correctly decipher a captcha...

Answer (score 0):

I can't recommend this because I've never used it, but I know a small company that had decent luck with [A Naive Bayesian Spam Filter for C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/BayesianCS.aspx) by Jason Kester.

I would personally recommend using a 3rd party like Akismet though. Spam filtering is tough business and it is always better to delegate that to someone who can and will keep up with the spammers' techniques over time.