# Asp.Net MVC 5 Spam message detection library

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

I have a contact us page in my website designed in Asp.net MVC 5.
I receive a lot of spam (unethical) emails from there.
I need a library that can check the email content before being sent in Asp.net mvc.

I tried to use ML library but as I found its only for .net core.

Answer (score 0):

To prevent spam message in a web application the first line of defense should be a [Captcha](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAPTCHA).

If you already have a captcha setup then you can consider the answers from this thread: [Spam filter for ASP.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/361707/spam-filter-for-asp-net)